# Get all nested Text Elements in a Google Doc using Selection's RangeElements

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

[image]

In a document similar to the above, I can get all the paragraphs with the following code:

`var paras = body.getParagraphs();`

Notice that the code above not only returns the top level paragraphs but also returns all the sub-level paragraphs inside `ListItem`s, `Table`s etc.

How can I do the same thing within a selected range? Following code only returns top level elements.

```
const selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
var rangeElements = selection.getRangeElements();
```

For example, the table above contains 9 non-empty paragraphs and I'd like to process them one by one if they are in selection.

What I'm trying to achieve is similar to translating the text in a selection by preserving the formatting, tables, list items etc. as much as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.getRangeElements()` returns an array of [RangeElements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element). A range element is a wrapper object that is used to help us deal with partial selections. We can call `.getElement()` on each item in this array to get the [Element object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element) which is a **very** generic object that can represent almost any piece of a Google Doc. `Elements` have a `.getType()` method that return an [ElementType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type) enum; and there are *a lot* of them!

---

Let's use what we know so far to see what the possible types are in a Google Doc (I've [created one similar to yours (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yb76.png) as an example):

```
function selectionHasWhichTypes() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var selection = doc.getSelection();
  var rangeElems = selection.getRangeElements();

  rangeElems.forEach(function(elem){
    var elem = elem.getElement();

    Logger.log(elem.getType());
  });
}

//Logger OUTPUT:
PARAGRAPH
PARAGRAPH
PARAGRAPH
PARAGRAPH
PARAGRAPH
LIST_ITEM
LIST_ITEM
LIST_ITEM
PARAGRAPH
PARAGRAPH
PARAGRAPH
TABLE
PARAGRAPH
```

**Ah Ha!** It looks like we only have to deal with [PARAGRAPH](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph.html), [LIST_ITEM](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item.html), and [TABLE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table.html) ElementTypes *for now*, but let's keep their **children** in mind too (We will find out that these are 3 of 5 that can have children). This sounds like a job for a **recursive function** that will continually dig down into child elements until we've found and dealt with them all.

---

**So let's try that.** This next part may look confusing but essentially it is finding an element, checking if it has children, then looking at those to see if *they* have children, and so on. We *also* want to check if we are getting **new** ElementTypes to deal with as well...

```
function selectionHasWhichTypes() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var selection = doc.getSelection();
  var rangeElems = selection.getRangeElements();

  rangeElems.forEach(function(elem){
    var elem = elem.getElement();

    elemsHaveWhatChildElems(elem, elem.getType());

  });
}

function elemsHaveWhatChildElems(elem, typeChain){
  var elemType = elem.getType();
  if(elemType == "TABLE" || elemType == "LIST_ITEM" || elemType == "PARAGRAPH"){ //Lets see if element is one of our basic 3. If so they could have children.
    var numChildren = elem.getNumChildren(); //How many children are there?
    if(numChildren > 0){
      for(var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++){ //Let's go through them.
        var child = elem.getChild(i);
        elemsHaveWhatChildElems(child, typeChain + "." + child.getType()); //Recursion step to look for more children.
      }
    }else{
       Logger.log(typeChain); //Let's log the chain of Parent to Child elements.
    }
  }else{
    Logger.log("*" + typeChain); //Let's mark the new elemTypeChains we have not seen.
  }
}

//Logger OUTPUT:
*PARAGRAPH.TEXT
PARAGRAPH
*PARAGRAPH.HORIZONTAL_RULE
PARAGRAPH
*PARAGRAPH.TEXT
*LIST_ITEM.TEXT
*LIST_ITEM.TEXT
*LIST_ITEM.TEXT
PARAGRAPH
*PARAGRAPH.TEXT
PARAGRAPH
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW
PARAGRAPH
```

Alright, so each line of the log is a chain of Elements and their children. We have some **new ElementTypes** ([HORIZONTAL_RULE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-rule.html), [TABLE_ROW](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row.html), and [TEXT](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text.html)). If a chain is only a `Paragraph` and has no children, indicated by 'PARAGRAPH.' we can **ignore it** as it is a blank line. We can also ignore `HORIZONTAL_RULE` as this *obviously* won't contain text.

**If we have gotten to a TEXT Element** it means we can perform our function (ie. for OP it would be a translation) like we have done with LIST_ITEMs and PARAGRAPHs. However, we *still* have to deal with [TableRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row) Objects (which logs like this: `TABLE.TABLE_ROW`). This is **similar to our main 3 elements** and can be used with our `if(elemType == "TABLE" || elemType == "LIST_ITEM" || elemType == "PARAGRAPH")` which changes to `if(elemType == "TABLE" || elemType == "LIST_ITEM" || elemType == "PARAGRAPH" || elemType == "TABLE_ROW")`.

This gives us another new Element in our chain; [TableCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell) (logs like: `TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL`), which we can *again* add to our if statement making it: `if(elemType == "TABLE" || elemType == "LIST_ITEM" || elemType == "PARAGRAPH" || elemType == "TABLE_ROW" || elemType == "TABLE_CELL")`

---

**Time to see what happens** when we've dealt with Table ElementTypes.

```
function selectionHasWhichtypeChains() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var selection = doc.getSelection();
  var rangeElems = selection.getRangeElements();

  rangeElems.forEach(function(elem){
    var elem = elem.getElement();

    elemsHaveWhatChildElems(elem, elem.getType());

  });
}

function elemsHaveWhatChildElems(elem, typeChain){
  var elemType = elem.getType();
  if(elemType == "TABLE" || elemType == "LIST_ITEM" || elemType == "PARAGRAPH" || elemType == "TABLE_ROW" || elemType == "TABLE_CELL"){ //Lets see if element is one of our basic 5 if so they could have children.
    var numChildren = elem.getNumChildren(); //How many children are there?
    if(numChildren > 0){
      for(var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++){ //Let's go through them.
        var child = elem.getChild(i);
        elemsHaveWhatChildElems(child, typeChain + "." + child.getType()); //Recursion step to look for more children.
      }
    }else{
       Logger.log(typeChain); //Let's log the chain of Parent to Child elements.
    }
  }else{
    Logger.log("*" + typeChain); //Let's mark the new elemTypeChains we have not seen.
  }
}

//Logger OUTPUT:
*PARAGRAPH.TEXT
PARAGRAPH
*PARAGRAPH.HORIZONTAL_RULE
PARAGRAPH
*PARAGRAPH.TEXT
*LIST_ITEM.TEXT
*LIST_ITEM.TEXT
*LIST_ITEM.TEXT
PARAGRAPH
*PARAGRAPH.TEXT
PARAGRAPH
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.TEXT
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.TEXT
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.TEXT
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.TEXT
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.TEXT
TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.TEXT
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.HORIZONTAL_RULE
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.TEXT
*TABLE.TABLE_ROW.TABLE_CELL.PARAGRAPH.TEXT
PARAGRAPH
```

---

**This is great!** We've reached into the depths of every parent element and reached either **a [Text Element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text)** or a **blank paragraph**! From here we can slightly modify our code to add the functions that we want to perform while maintaining the structure of the document:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var selection = doc.getSelection();
  var rangeElems = selection.getRangeElements(); //Get main Elements of selection

  rangeElems.forEach(function(elem){ //Let's rn through each to find ALL of their children.
    var elem = elem.getElement(); //We have an ElementType. Let's get the full element.
    getNestedTextElements(elem, elem.getType()); //Time to go down the rabbit hole.
  });
}

function getNestedTextElements(elem, typeChain){
  var elemType = elem.getType();
  if(elemType == "TABLE" || elemType == "LIST_ITEM" || elemType == "PARAGRAPH" || elemType == "TABLE_ROW" || elemType == "TABLE_CELL"){ //Lets see if element is one of our basic 5, if so they could have children.
    var numChildren = elem.getNumChildren(); //How many children are there?
    if(numChildren > 0){
      for(var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++){ //Let's go through them.
        var child = elem.getChild(i);
        getNestedTextElements(child, typeChain + "." + child.getType()); //Recursion step to look for more children.
      }
    }
  }else if(elemType == "TEXT"){
    //THIS IS WHERE WE CAN PERFORM OUR OPERATIONS ON THE TEXT ELEMENT
    var text = elem.getText();


  }else{
    Logger.log("*" + typeChain); //Let's log the new elem we dont deal with now - for future proofing.
  }
}
```

**BOOM! Done.** I know this is a really long post, but I've broken down each section of the solution into parts to help new Apps Script coders understand the structure of a Selection (and Document Body, I guess) and how to modify it when the structure is very complicated (many nested Elements). **I really hope this was helpful**. If anybody sees a piece that can be improved, let me know.

---

*As a note to OP: Be warned that this doesn't necessarily deal with partial selections of an Element, but that can easily be dealt with by modifying the first function a little to check for `isPartial()` on the [RangeElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element).*

Comment: I can't thank enough. This is a really good explanation. I tried to understand the document structure by reading official documentation but I think they try to hide some details on purpose. I tried the debugging tool to see more details, even tried JSON.stringify(doc) which prints an empty object. I am also new to Javascript which makes things harder for me.