# Google Docs script to insert another document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am looking to use custom menu to insert another entire document.

The idea is that I have created a set of google docs with custom tables in each and then from the menu the user can just run a script to insert the table/template.

Creating the menu is easy (.createMenu) and adding menu items I can do. But how then do I create a script that copies the entirety of another google document (based on doc.id) and inserts into my current document?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by getting the [Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body) of one document and appending its child Elements to the current document.

```
function appendTemplate(templateID) {

  var thisDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var thisBody = thisDoc.getBody();

  var templateDoc = DocumentApp.openById(templateID); //Pass in id of doc to be used as a template.
  var templateBody = templateDoc.getBody();

  for(var i=0; i<templateBody.getNumChildren();i++){ //run through the elements of the template doc's Body.
    switch (templateBody.getChild(i).getType()) { //Deal with the various types of Elements we will encounter and append.
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
        thisBody.appendParagraph(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM:
        thisBody.appendListItem(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
        thisBody.appendTable(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
    }
  }

  return thisDoc;
}
```

If you are interested in learning more about the structure of a Document's Body object, I wrote up a [long answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54780659/1691677). It covers Selections mainly, but the information is all applicable.

Comment: this doesn't work with bullet points

Comment: Looks like there are quite a few more ElementTypes to deal with. See the [Enum list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type) and then use functions of [Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body) to append. Not sure if these were added after my answer but easy enough to modify and add to code!