# What's the preferred way to insert a bulleted list into a Google Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, bulletedlist

I'm trying to get familiar with Google Apps Script in a Google doc and want to be able to insert a bulleted list with various levels of nesting. I thought I was using `body.insertListItem` correctly, but what's odd is that when I add subsequent list item, it seems to mess up the nesting levels and glyphs of previously inserted items.

For example, here's my sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var body = doc.getBody()
  var cursor = doc.getCursor()
  
  var element = body.insertParagraph(0, "hello world")
  element.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1)
  var ixElement = body.getChildIndex(element)
  var listItem = body.insertListItem(ixElement+1, "List")
  listItem.setNestingLevel(0)
  listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)
  var listItem2 = body.insertListItem(ixElement+2, "List Item")
  listItem2.setNestingLevel(1)
  listItem2.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.HOLLOW_BULLET)
  var listItem3 = body.insertListItem(ixElement+3, "2nd List Item")
  listItem3.setNestingLevel(1)
  listItem3.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.HOLLOW_BULLET)  
  var listItem4 = body.insertListItem(ixElement+4, "2x nested list Item")
  listItem4.setNestingLevel(2)
  listItem4.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET)    
  //listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)
}
```

The problem is that is that the only call to `.setGlyphType` that "sticks" is the last one that's called. Each previous bullet gets changed.

Expected:

[image: expected image]

Actual:

[image: actual image]

You can see in the image for the actual results that the first list item should have been a bullet, but was changed to a number. (If I call `listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)` again it will change back to a bullet). This makes me think I may be going about this the wrong way. Is there a better way to insert `listItem` elements into a Google Doc with Apps Script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue:

- `body.insertListItem(index, *text*)` creates a new list item from text with a default glype type. This also changes according to the nesting level. When this newly created list item is appended to the existing list item, the existing list item's glype is overwritten.

#### Solutions:

- Create a listItem with the required glypetype before inserting  the list item. This list item can then be used with `body.insertListItem(index, *listItem*)` method instead of `body.insertListItem(index, *text*)`

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc
function fixedMyFunction2() {
  'use strict';
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var element = body.insertParagraph(0, 'hello world');
  element.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  var ixElement = body.getChildIndex(element);
  var listItem = body.insertListItem(ixElement + 1, 'List');
  listItem.setNestingLevel(0);
  listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);

  var listItem2 = listItem
    .copy()
    .setNestingLevel(1)
    .setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.HOLLOW_BULLET);
  listItem2.setText('List Item');
  body.insertListItem(ixElement + 2, listItem2);

  var listItem3 = listItem2.copy();
  listItem3.setText('2nd ListItem');
  body.insertListItem(ixElement + 3, listItem3);

  var listItem4 = listItem2
    .copy()
    .setNestingLevel(2)
    .setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
  listItem4.setText('2x nested listItem');
  body.insertListItem(ixElement + 4, listItem4);
}
```

- Without much modifications to your script. This also works, if you set `setGlyphType`s after appending at last :

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc
function fixedMyFunction() {
  'use strict';
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var element = body.insertParagraph(0, 'hello world');
  element.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  var ixElement = body.getChildIndex(element);
  var listItem = body.insertListItem(ixElement + 1, 'List');
  listItem.setNestingLevel(0);

  var listItem2 = body.insertListItem(ixElement + 2, 'List Item');
  listItem2.setNestingLevel(1);
  var listItem3 = body.insertListItem(ixElement + 3, '2nd List Item');
  listItem3.setNestingLevel(1);

  var listItem4 = body.insertListItem(ixElement + 4, '2x nested list Item');
  listItem4.setNestingLevel(2);

  //Setglyphs at last
  listItem4.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
  listItem3.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.HOLLOW_BULLET);
  listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
}
```

Comment: In your environment, the order of `listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);`, `listItem3.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.HOLLOW_BULLET);` and `listItem4.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);` after the list items were set doesn't work. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I thought so at first. But checking  again. That's not the case. I figured out the actual issue. And the explanation of the issue is consistent with the theory that order doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested the same situation before, the important point was that at first, the list items are set and then, the GlyphTypes are set. In that case, the order of GlyphType didn't affect to the list items. So I have wanted to confirm whether the specification had been changed. From updated your question, I think that your answer should be upvoted.

Comment: That's a clever solution, copying the existing `listItem` so you can manipulate the object before inserting it back into the document body. It's still a bit odd to me why it behaves this way, but I appreciate the workaround.

Comment: @BenMcCormack *It's still a bit odd to me why it behaves this way* Do you understand *When this newly created list item is appended to the existing list item, the existing list item's glype is overwritten.* ? If your script only does upto this: `var listItem = body.insertListItem(ixElement+1, "List")
  listItem.setNestingLevel(0)
  listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)
  var listItem2 = body.insertListItem(ixElement+2, "List Item")`, You'll see what I mean(the existing glype is overwritten). I agree it's still odd

Answer (score 0):

In my case (adding items in a loop) it was helpful to set the glyph type for each nesting level:

```
function buildBulletedList(){

  // we use the number of leading blanks (divided by 2) to determine the indenting level
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody(); 

  const items=['- item1', '  - item1.1', '- item2', '  - item2.1', '    - item2.1.1', '      - item2.1.1.1'];
  let index=0;
  for (i of items) {
      
      let left=i.split('-')[0];
      let lvl=(left.match(/\s/g) || []).length/2; // 1 nesting level is 2 blanks
      //Logger.log(lvl);
      let text=i.replace(/\s*\-\s/g,'');    
      index++; // this is a very simple case adding the list items to an empty document
      //Logger.log(index);
      
      let listItem=body.insertListItem(index, text,);

      // this fails / unexpected behaviour (as already described):     
      /*    
      listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET); 
      listItem.setNestingLevel(lvl);
      // doubling/repeating after indenting does not help
      listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET); 
      */

      // this works:
      for (nl=0; nl<=lvl; nl++){
        listItem.setNestingLevel(nl);
        //listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET); // all levels same bullet point
        // we can also vary here, e.g.
        if (nl==0) {
          listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET); 
        }
        else {
          listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.HOLLOW_BULLET); 
        }

      }       
      
  }    

}
```