# Populate Google Sheet with Google Docs in Drive that contain certain words

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

Here's a summary of what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Run Apps Script that searches all Google Docs in a Drive.
2. If the script finds a document that contains at least one of three words (always in the header or footer), then it outputs this into a row within a Google Sheet, capturing the Google Doc ID, the Doc's name, a link to it, and the word that it found in the search (optionally, it'd be nice to include the owner name). Note that the header/footer will only ever contain one of a few words -- never a combination of them.

E.g., find all files that have "alice", "bob", or "carol" in the header or footer; log these entries as separate rows in a Google Sheet.

Google Doc ID | Alice Project Summary 2021 | Link to Doc | "alice"

I feel like I've found what I need within the Apps Script API, and found some similar search results, but can't quite piece this together.

Totally happy to expound more if that helps or if this is unclear!

Cheers for any pointers! (Even if it's just pointing out that my searching wasn't comprehensive enough.)

Comment: In your situation, how many Google Documents you want to search are there? About `I feel like I've found what I need within the Apps Script API, and found some similar search results, but can't quite piece this together.`, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Prior to posting, I came across findText(searchPattern) [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern], which leads to the RangeElement class [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778375/get-all-nested-text-elements-in-a-google-doc-using-selections-rangeelements]. I haven't found a starting point for going this route, although I'm not convinced this is the optimal way to do so. I'll still see what I can build out as I research. (Also, I'd imagine there could be hundreds/thousands of Google Docs in a drive, so that's something to consider.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between Apps Script API and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, what is `E.g.,` of `E.g., find all files that have "alice", "bob", or "carol" in the header or footer; log these entries as separate rows in a Google Sheet.`? In your question, you want to search the text from the body except for the header and footer? I would like to think of the solution by correctly understanding your question. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: My apologies as I realize this probably isn't as clear as it could be! What I want is a spreadsheet filled with the document IDs and URLs of all Google Docs within my drive that contain certain keywords in the header/footer. For example, if I want my Google Sheet to contain every Google Doc that contains the word "confidential" in the footer, I'd use an Apps Script to auto-run when I open the Google Sheet (using a trigger). The Apps Script would do the job of searching through all Google Docs in the Drive and exporting the details of the desire Google Docs into the Google Sheet.

Comment: For context, I've used Apps Script with triggers before, for automating email. An example: a user fills out a Google Form and as soon as they submit it to the corresponding Google Sheet (that holds the form submissions), a trigger will initiate an Apps Script that can automatically email the person who submitted the form with some arbitrary messaging. I'm looking for that kind of automation here, where as soon as I open the Google Sheet, an Apps Script will initiate that finds all of the relevant Google Docs in my drive and pulls their "metadata" into the Google Sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, you have a Google Spreadsheet. When you open the Google Spreadsheet, you want to run a script for searching all Google Document files in your Google Drive by checking the header and footer of the Document and putting the searched result to the specification sheet in the Google Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct! (I attempted to move this to chat, per the notification to avoid extended discussions in comments, but could not, due to have few reputation points [too new as a poster].)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize. And also, in my environment, I do have not hundreds/thousands of Google Docs. By this, I cannot test your situation. I apologize for this. So when you test this script, if the script cannot retrieve all Google Documents you want to retrieve, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Google Spreadsheet. When you open the Google Spreadsheet, you want to run a script for searching all Google Document files in your Google Drive by checking the header and footer of the Document and putting the searched result to the specification sheet in the Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to search Google Document that the values of "alice", "bob", or "carol" are included in the header and footer. And, you want to put the values on the Spreadsheet.
- There are hundreds/thousands of Google Docs in your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Search the Google Document files that the values of "alice", "bob", or "carol" are included in the header and footer using the search query of Drive API.

   - By this method, I thought that the search cost might be able to be reduced a little.
2. Check the header and footer of each Google Document. When the values of "alice", "bob", or "carol" are found, the Document ID, title, link, and searched value are put to an array.
3. Put the array on Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set the sheet name. And, in this sample script, Drive API is used. So [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

And also, [please install OnOpen trigger to the function of `myFunction` as the installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). By this, when you open Spreadsheet, the script is automatically run. In the case of the installable trigger, the maximum execution time is 6 minutes and Drive API can be used. On the other hand, the simple trigger is 30 seconds. Please be careful about this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const searchTexts = ["alice", "bob", "carol"];

  // 1. Search the Google Document files that the values of "alice", "bob", or "carol" are included in the header ahd footer using the search query of Drive API.
  const q = `mimeType = '${MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}' and (` + searchTexts.map(s => `fullText contains '${s}'`).join(" or ") + ")";
  let ar = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const res = Drive.Files.list({q, pageToken, maxResults: 1000, fields: "items(id, title, alternateLink)"});
    if (res.items.length > 0) {
      ar = ar.concat(res.items);
    }
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  // 2. Check the header and footer of each Google Document. When the values of "alice", "bob", or "carol" are found, the Document ID, title, link and searched value are put to an array.
  const values = ar.reduce((ar, {id, title, alternateLink}) => {
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
    let temp = [];
    const header = doc.getHeader();
    if (header) {
      const hText = header.getText();
      temp = temp.concat(searchTexts.filter(e => hText.includes(e)));
    }
    const footer = doc.getFooter();
    if (footer) {
      const fText = footer.getText();
      temp = temp.concat(searchTexts.filter(e => fText.includes(e)));
    }
    if (temp.length > 0) ar.push([id, title, alternateLink, temp.join(",")]);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 3. Put the array to Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheetname.
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, I do have not hundreds/thousands of Google Docs. And, I cannot test your situation. So please test the above script in your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files)

Comment: This worked brilliantly and now I see why I hit a wall with solving it -- I completely missed the need for using the Drive API. Had I considered that I would likely have came upon the references you mentioned. Thanks a ton for this! (Also, sorry for my lack of an example to start from. The functions/classes I found were so far off that I couldn't find a starting point. I really appreciate the effort and given this solution, I'll definitely be a lot more capable with future projects that require interaction with Drive.)

Comment: @Justin Troutman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your situation, I guessed that 2 steps for searching many Google Documents might be suitable. Because when the files are searched with Drive API, the process cost is lower than that of Drive service of GAS. From your question, I could understand that my guess might have been correct. Thank you. And also, from your cooperation, I could correctly understand your question. Thank you, too.